# How do you handle design templates in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We're developing a few web apps using ASP.NET MVC 4/5. This company is new to MVC but has created a few WebForms applications. My question, what is the nearest equivalent to the templates used in WebForms development? I'm not aware of anything even close. In lieu of a template concept, how do you control / ensure everyone on the team is keeps the same layout? CSS can be used for colors and typography but what about layout and non-CSS?

Comment: MVC5 allows you to mix webforms and mvc. While I personally would not really want to do that, if you have legacy templates it can make sense for the end points to be mvc calls while the front end ui remains webforms. If you want to look into trying that, Rachel Appel has some good information on the approach. http://rachelappel.com/integrating-aspnet-web-forms-and-aspnetmvc

Comment: @TravisJ: *All* versions of MVC can mix WebForms and Razor Views. Not unique to MVC5.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Razor Layouts](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-3/mvc-3-razor-layouts), Scott Gu has an excellent series [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor):

Answer (score 0):

Razor uses "layouts". They're just views (`.cshtml`/`.vbhtml` files) with at least one piece of code inside, `@RenderBody()`, which is where the rendered content of the view using the layout will be placed. Everything else is optional, though it's common to implement "sections" using `@RenderSection("SectionName", true/false)`, where a `true` value indicates that the secction is required (must be defined in the view that calls this layout) and a `false` value indicates that it's optional. Your view then implements the section using:

```
@section SectionName
{
    <!-- something here -->
}
```

View will by default use the layout defined at `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`, but you can make them use something else by either explicitly specifying the layout in the view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyAwesomeLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Or by placing a `_ViewStart.cshtml` with that code in the view directory you want it to apply to. Views in that directory and all subdirectories within will then use that layout, unless they have their own explicit layout or the subdirectory they are in has its own `_ViewStart.cshtml` file.

Layouts can also inherit from other layouts, but they must redefine any sections in the original layout in order to expose them to views. For example:

**Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
    </body>
</html>
```

**Views\Shared\_FooLayout.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<p>Foo</p>

@RenderBody()

@section Scripts
{
    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
}
```